# How to use google word2vec model in azure machine learning studio?

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec, azure-machine-learning-service

For using the word2vec model , you need to have word2vec vectors file(which is a .bin file) installed. Is there a way to import this file from a url or have it stored somewhere in the azure machine learning studio (like the azure blob storage) ?